# Windows 10 Cordova/Ionic link makes phone open store link

Tags: c#, cordova, ionic-framework, windows-10-universal

I'm using the default template and generated code from the template (Cordova Multiplatform Template 1.0.2). However when I tap a list item this messagebox shows up instead of navigating:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/#get-your-app-running-on-windows-10)

> Partial pages don't load?
>   When you are using the AngularJS routing module (Ionic starter templates often use this module), you may need to include a call to aHrefSanitizationWhitelist.
>
> If you see the dialog box shown here, you have likely run into this
>   issue.
>
> Typically, you include the code fix in app.js or wherever you are
>   calling your module configuration code:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {
      $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|ghttps?|ms-appx|ms-appx-web|x-wmapp0):/);

      $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|ms-appx|ms-appx-web|x-wmapp0):|data:image\//);
```